# Download Android ISO on PC

Tags: android, android-source, iso, rom

Where can I get the Android iso file for PC. I want to know the download link. Please tell me about it!

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: google **Android x86** should get what you're looking for.

Answer (score 9):

Android-x86.org has readily and legally available Android ISO images that run on laptops/PC's/tablets.....there are also builds from their open source base available from others: tabletsx86.org / android-x86.sceners.org / etc.

forum here: http://groups.google.com/group/android-x86

android-x86.org iso's here: http://www.android-x86.org/download

Answer (score 5):

There is no readily and legally available Android ISO image.

All device manufacturers like Lenovo, Dell, Asus, etc have their ISO builds that only work on the respective hardware.

I imagine you would want to make your own Android build. This can be done by getting the latest Android source code, and building it on your device. It's quite simple to set up, actually. I have done it with a Linux VirtualBox. Be advised though, the build can take up to 4 hours :)

More detailed instructions can be found here: [Android Open Source Project](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html)